# How to focus on pydev console prompt with keyboard?

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console, pydev

It seems there is no way to focus pydev console prompt even with window switch. Does anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think i had to hack this by using a windows macro program to put a mouse click there :)
  I used Macro Express